Python not catching a Paramiko IncompatiblePeer exception
I have the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paramiko
from paramiko import SSHClient
from paramiko.ssh_exception import IncompatiblePeer

xkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('./tests/ssh/rsa/valid')
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
try:
    client.connect('192.168.1.2', username='username', pkey=xkey)
except IncompatiblePeer as e:
    print('got IncompatiblePeer')
except paramiko.ssh_exception.IncompatiblePeer as e:
    print('got IncompatiblePeer2')
except:
    print("raw except")

Running it give:

Exception (client): Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cpp/xython/home/celery/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2194, in run
self._handler_tableptype
File "/home/cpp/xython/home/celery/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2314, in _negotiate_keys
self._parse_kex_init(m)
File "/home/cpp/xython/home/celery/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2603, in _parse_kex_init
raise IncompatiblePeer(
paramiko.ssh_exception.IncompatiblePeer: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
got IncompatiblePeer

So it catch the exception but still print an uncatched stacktrace even If I can handle it
What can I do to silence it?
I tried all different exceptions paramiko.ssh_exception.IncompatiblePeer vs just IncompatiblePeer.
Note that the IncompatiblePeer behaviour is normal. I want to test that Paramiko fail to connect on this host due to mismatch OpenSSH ciphers.

That's probably an output from logger, not an uncatched exception dump.
See the transport.py code:
except SSHException as e:
    self._log(
        ERROR,
        "Exception ({}): {}".format(
            "server" if self.server_mode else "client", e
        ),
    )
    self._log(ERROR, util.tb_strings())
    self.saved_exception = e


Thanks, it was effectively a logger output
